# Implementing Value objects in DDD when I have lot of Amount fields to deal with

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

I want to create Value objects for lots of amounts that I deal with in my application like InstallmentAmount, OutstandingAmount, FinancedAmount, PricipalAmount, etc and mostly all have only BigDecimal value which i would use for calculations.

Here is it a good idea to have a Amount Value object and extend from that for all these Objects?

Comment: Why do you have to have all of these different types?

Comment: Aren't the types of the value objects all the same and they just get a different meaning from the context in which they're used in? Using something like `Money` (which contains the amount and the currency) I'd probably do something like this: `Money installment; Money outstanding; Money financed; ...`.

Comment: @TimMoore, I would like to have some logic in each of these, like some invariants and the specific calculation of how we may derive at that value, eg. FinancedAmount = NetAmount - DownPayment - TradeInAmount etc.

Comment: @Thomas, If I have most of the objects as type Money then i am thinking i wont get the compile time type checks etc. Also, I would like to have some logic in each of these, like some invariants and the specific calculation logic, which should i add in money class itself? like calculateNetAmount(), calculateFinancedAmount() etc

Comment: Well, the value objects should be independent from each other as well as from the entity they're used with (value objects should be shareable so they shouldn't have any notion of the entity at all). Thus those calculation methods don't belong into the value objects since they seem to depend on the entity. Whether invariant checks are moved to the value objects depends on whether they apply to _all_ of those values or not, i.e. an invariant for "distance must never be negative" could be part of a `Distance` value object but "Distance must be at most 100m" probably doesn't belong there.

Comment: Compile time checks can be helpful but you need to think about whether they actually help you so much that they warrant having those extra classes (it that's all they're used for once any context-dependent calculation is moved out of the VOs).

Comment: I am also having to deal with a lot of Dates like installmentStartDate, DownPaymentDate. Any suggestion for handling dates?